# How to get Dropdown selected value on client side onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have written a code for dropdown selected index changed event at client side using onchange event and create one JavaScript function.
Now, I want to retrieve selected values in this function. How can I get this value?

Comment: did you figure it out? Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#DropDownlist:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you selected text.

```
$("#mydropdownid option:selected").text();
```

This will give you selected value

```
$('#mydropdownid').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML :**

```
<select id="mySelect" class="myClass">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery :**

Now for getting selected value you can use the one of the following:

**ONE :**

```
var selected_value = $("#mySelect").val();
```

**TWO :**

```
var selected_value = $(".myClass").val();
```

**THREE :**

```
var dropdown = $("#mySelect option:selected");
var selected_value = dropdown.val();
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest, inside the event handler:

```
$('#elementID').change(function(event) {

   event.target.value;

};
```

event is the event object sent to the handler, target is the object in the DOM from which the event generated, and value it's the DOM element current value. In the case of a select box this will work perfectly to get your selected value.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged jQuery, I assume that's what you are using.
Simply use jQuery [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var v = $("#yourSelectID").val();
alert("The value is: " + v);
```

You should also be able to use plain javascript:

```
var e = document.getElementById("yourSelectID");
var v = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert("The value is: " + v);
```